# Using {!$Credential.OAuthToken} in an apex Class

Tags: rest-api, namedcredentials, merge-field

I wrote the code below.

```java
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint('callout:namedCredential/services/apexrest/customRestAPIGetAccount`);
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}'); // returns error

Http http = new Http(); 
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req); 
System.debug(res.getBody());
return res.getBody();
```

If i try to [use the merge field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm), I get errors. Named credentials is supposed bypass the need to post the OauthToken. But I can't get it to work.

Has anyone been able to get this work?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I gave you some general advice, but in the future, please remember to include the errors you're getting. There are a large number of reasons why your code might not be working, and saying "I get errors" does not narrow it down much. An actual copy of the error would be ideal. Please read [ask] to learn more about asking questions on our network. If you [edit] your question to include more information, we can help you better.

Comment: It's not Bearer -  it's OAuth:   req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');

Comment: Thanks for the replies. To answer both questions. Named credential has Generate auth header and merge fields checked. The merge field is returning as string. Instead of placing the reference, it's returning the literal, "OAuth {!$Credentials.OAuthToken}" which throws 'INVALID_AUTH_HEADER' error. I am running this in developer console

Answer (score 1):

If you check "Generate Authorization Header", you don't need the merge fields, as the Named Credential covers this for you. This should be your first option to try. If you do not check that box, then you need to check "Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header", then you can use the code you demonstrated in your question. If that fails, you need to check your provider's documentation to determine why the call is failing/you're getting errors.

In this case, it looks like you're trying to call a Salesforce service, so "Generate Authorization Header" should be the option you should use. You do not need your own Authorization header. If you're getting errors, you need to make sure you have the correct endpoint, that your session is active, and that you have access to the custom Rest API resource you're attempting to use.

Comment: Although, doesn't answer why the merge field is rendering as a string literal. GenerateAuthHeader on or off = same output for me..
\n
code:
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');
    system.debug('req ' + req.getHeader('Authorization'));

log:
    08:26:30:003 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|req OAuth {!$Credential.OAuthToken}

This page seems pretty clear about how to do it.  Almost like there's a system setting I have off or something..
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm

Comment: sorry that didn't render nicely